# emulating git pull --rebase by git push

Tags: git

I have a server named `production` with git source code checked out from master branch and executed.
In addition I have a `development` server with the clone of the git repo where I do code modifications.
I would like to sync the source code `development -> production`.
My initial idea was running `git pull --rebase` on the `production` server to get the up-to-date commited files. However, because of network constraints (firewall etc') `production` can't contact `development` but the other way around works: `development` can `git pull/push` from `production`.
When I tried to push I got the following message:

```
+ git push origin master
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master        
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository        
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent        
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match        
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.        
remote: error:         
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to        
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into        
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you        
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some        
remote: error: other way.        
remote: error:         
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set        
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

What I understand is that in order to push changes that I should configure `receive.denyCurrentBranch` and then after push execute `git reset --hard` on production master branch. This will in addition overwrite uncommitted changes on production.
Is there a safer way doing that? For example sometimes someone might ssh to production machine and change the code there directly. I prefer my command will fail in such case. Another example is that the production server has some untracked files that I am afraid to overwrite/delete.

Is there another way other than the `git reset --hard` on production server?

Comment: Push to a different branch on the production server, then ssh into it and use `git pull OTHER_BRANCH`.

Comment: Maybe `git push -f origin master`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your setup, why are you trying to pull to/from the development server, where is your main (probably bare) repository which acts as a central host for code? If you don't have this I'd suggest creating it (guessing from your setup, you should make this on prod) and then both Dev can push/pull to it and prod can pull from it

Comment: @nick - I didn't want to complicate my question but my actual setup is more complicated. The server I called `development` is actually a proxy that pulls from the main bare repository. My main issue is that `production` has a network constraint that prevent it from pulling from other servers.

Comment: Gotcha. You can still setup a bare repository on production too (git is intended to be distributed in this way so won't be a problem), and from the sounds of your setup this should work?

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good idea. For now I am testing what @LasseV.Karlsen suggested

Comment: " For example sometimes someone might ssh to production machine and change the code there directly." This not an ideal practice. You should not change committed code for configuration changes for different environments. Instead use environment variables or configuration files that are not committed to the git repo. Neither should you make any direct code changes on production. These should be committed and go through your usual deployment process.

Comment: As for untracked files, either commit them or add them to `.gitignore` so they won't be committed to git.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions where mentioned in the comments:

1. Pushing to another branch on `production`, the `git pull . BRANCH_NAME` on `production` machine.
2. Set up additional bare repo on `production` machine. Since git is distributed, the server can be on any machine, and for my case with the network constraints it just simple to put it on `production`.

I ended up implementing #1.